# Creating new named handlers when using php-fpm and mod_proxy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

When researching how to use php-fpm with mod_proxy, you get lots of code like this:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

I've also seen configurations where you use define to name a variable to use in AddHandler and SetHandler

```
Define php5-fpm "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
AddHandler ${php5-fpm} .php
```

However, I've yet to find a way to make a new named handler, as opposed to a placeholder variable. I've yet to find a way to make a new handler named `application/x-httpd-php`

For example, we have a number of applications with .htaccess files with blocks like this:

```
<Files foo_php_file>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

To change a file named `foo_php_file` to be run as a PHP script. Instead of having to change every one of these .htaccess files to use a `${php5-fpm}` or `${php-fpm}` define, I'd like to be able to create the `application/x-httpd-php` so the .htaccess files can be used as is.

Is there a way to make a new named handler like this, so an fpm fastcgi setup can be backwards compatible with old .htaccess files that expected mod_php?